# Help with writing a polynomial series

Tags: syntax, series-expansion

I want to write and evaluate an expression something like

```
Sum[x[i] Product[y[j], {j(!=i), 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]
```

but with correct syntax, where n is a any number (say 4 as a concrete example).

Comment: You should probably get a stronger grip on Mathematica syntax

Comment: Sum[x[i]*Product[y[j], {j != i, n}], {i, 1, n}]

Comment: Perhaps `Sum[x[i] Product[y[j], {j, 1, n}]/y[i], {i, 1, n}] /. n-> 4`?

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate, because based on `j(!=i)` (sic) I believe it is.  If the answers there do not address your question please edit yours to make clear the difference reply here starting your comment with "@Mr.Wizard"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, if not elegant way to do it, is

```
With[{n = 4}, Sum[x[i] Product[If[j == i, 1, y[j]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]]
```

> ```
> x[4] y[1] y[2] y[3] + x[3] y[1] y[2] y[4] + x[2] y[1] y[3] y[4] + x[1] y[2] y[3] y[4]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
Tr[Times @@@ SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> x@i, {i_, j_} -> y@j}, {4, 4}]]
```

> x[4] y[1] y[2] y[3] + x[3] y[1] y[2] y[4] + x[2] y[1] y[3] y[4] + x[1] y[2] y[3] y[4]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly direct implementation of what you wanted:

```
n = 4;    
Sum[x[i] Product[y[j], {j, Delete[Range[n], i]}], {i, 1, n}]
```

and here's a way that uses Mathematica's pattern matching facilities:

```
n = 4;
Plus@@ReplaceList[Product[y[j], {j, 1, n}], y[i_] rest_ :> x[i] rest]
```

Both return

> x[4] y[1] y[2] y[3] + x[3] y[1] y[2] y[4] +  x[2] y[1] y[3] y[4] + x[1] y[2] y[3] y[4]

Comment: The `ReplaceList` version is the fastest submitted so far: https://gist.github.com/simonjtyler/6759252

Answer (score 1):

Another approach defines `f` to be all the `x`'s and `g` to be all the `y`'s. The sum of the products can then be written concisely as

```
n = 4; f = Array[x, n];  g = Array[y, n];
Total[f[[#]] (Times @@ g)/g[[#]] & /@ Range[n]]
```

which gives the desired sum

```
x[4] y[1] y[2] y[3] + x[3] y[1] y[2] y[4] + x[2] y[1] y[3] y[4] + x[1] y[2] y[3] y[4]
```